# Java can’t find file all of a sudden

Tags: java, file

[image: screenshot]

```
public class DailyReport {
    public static void main (String[] args){

        try {

            int c1 =0;
            int c2 =0;
            int c3 =0;
            int c4 =0;
            int c5 =0;
            int total =0;

            File file=new File ("InputSB.txt");
            Scanner in = new Scanner (file);
            int count=0;
            ArrayList <Person> per = new ArrayList <Person>();



            CaseList [] c = CaseList.values();
             System.out.println("---------Covid-19 Cases and Actions Required---------");
                for (CaseList casel: c){
                 System.out.printf("%-10s : %-30s%-10s%n" ,casel.toString(),  casel.getCaseBg(), casel.getCaseStatus());
             }

                System.out.println("");


                System.out.println("----------------COVID-19 CASE REPORT----------------");
                System.out.printf("%-5s%-10s%-8s%-20s%-15s", "CASE", "GENDER", "AGE", "BACKGROUND", "Status");
                System.out.println("");

                //ArrayList <Person> per = new ArrayList <Person> ();


            while (in.hasNext()) {
                String s= in.next();
                int fileage=in.nextInt();
                String filecase=in.next();      



                per.add(new Person (s,fileage));

                CaseList cases = Enum.valueOf(CaseList.class, filecase);


                System.out.printf("%-5d%-10s%-8s%-20s%-15s%\n", (count+1),per.get(count).getGender(),per.get(count).getAge()
                 ,cases.getCaseBg(), cases.getCaseStatus());


                 switch(cases){ //()

                    case CASE1: ++c1;
                            break;

                    case CASE2: ++c2;
                            break;

                    case CASE3: ++c3;
                            break;

                    case CASE4: ++c4;
                            break;

                    case CASE5: ++c5;
                            break;

                default: break;

            }

                count++;
            }
            in.close();

        System.out.println("\nTotal in Quarantine = " + (c1+c2));
        System.out.println("Total in ICU        = " + c3);
        System.out.println("Total Warded        = " + c4);
        System.out.println("Total Recovered     = " + c5);
        total = (c1+c2+c3+c4+c5);
        System.out.println("Total Cases = " +total);

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("File is not found");
        }
    }
}
//this is what printstacktrace gets

java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = '
'
    at java.base/java.util.Formatter.checkText(Formatter.java:2732)
    at java.base/java.util.Formatter.parse(Formatter.java:2718)
    at java.base/java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2655)
    at java.base/java.io.PrintStream.format(PrintStream.java:1139)
    at java.base/java.io.PrintStream.printf(PrintStream.java:1035)
    at DailyReport.main(DailyReport.java:57)

//line57
System.out.printf("%-5d%-10s%-8s%-20s%-15s%\n", (count+1),per.get(count).getGender(),per.get(count).getAge()
                 ,cases.getCaseBg(), cases.getCaseStatus()); //line58
```

With using just "input.txt" I can at least run the rest of my code.
With using anything else, such as file's absolute path, or folder/input.txt and others, it gives me the second result which the the immediate file not found.

My java files and input.txt file is located in the same folder.

So I’ve opened a java file where I’m reading in the .txt file, and everything is going fine and everything works accordingly, until I move my java files and .txt file ALL from my DESKTOP to a FOLDER ON MY DESKTOP.

All of a sudden, it keeps throwing me the file not found exception. There should be nothing wrong with my code as it ran perfectly fine UNTIL I moved it all to a new folder.

```
File file = new file ("input.txt");
Scanner in = new Scanner (file);
```

The thing is there should be nothing wrong with the code since it ran perfectly fine when everything was located in my desktop. But when I moved it into a folder it all went downhill.

Can somebody tell me if they have the same problem? I’m using a macOS so maybe that’s something.

Comment: Perhaps a stupid question, but have you updated the path from `input.txt` to `folder/input.txt`?

Comment: Give complete path of file.
Scanner in = new Scanner (new File("/home/user/desktop/myNewFolder/input.txt"))

Comment: that doesn’t work either... hold on, I’ll edit my question

Comment: How do you start your code? What commands or dialogs are you using?

Comment: The possible issue could be the path from where you are running the java class.

Comment: I've used the getAbsolutePath for my file for the path, but that doesn't work either. I'm really baffled at this point

Comment: ive pasted my code into the post, though I really just think its something to do with how I moved everything from the desktop into a folder... but for some reason nothing works to help find that txt file!

Comment: You are catching all exceptions and just assuming it is caused by the file not being found, that is not necessarily the case. I'd highly recommend using `e.printStackTrace()` to find out the actual problem, and post the exception stacktrace in your question.

Comment: oh Lordy what's this

Comment: Please [edit] your question, don't post the stacktrace in the comments, and specifically identify which line is line 57 in your code.

Comment: case statement having an issue, double-check it.

Comment: The problem is probably `System.out.printf("%-5d%-10s%-8s%-20s%-15s%\n"`, that `%\n` should either be `%n` or possibly `%%\n` depending on exactly what you want to do there. However the main takeaway should be to never catch wide exceptions like `Exception` and not log or print out the actual exception. If you want to handle the file not found condition, then specifically catch `FileNotFoundException`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is on this line:

```
System.out.printf("%-5d%-10s%-8s%-20s%-15s%\n", (count+1),per.get(count).getGender(),per.get(count).getAge()
             ,cases.getCaseBg(), cases.getCaseStatus());
```

The pattern ends with `%\n` which is not a known conversion pattern.

If your plan was to print the percentage character, followed by a line break, according to the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)  (check the "Conversions" section) you should double it: `%%`

Change your line to :

```
System.out.printf("%-5d%-10s%-8s%-20s%-15s%%\n", (count+1),per.get(count).getGender(),per.get(count).getAge()
             ,cases.getCaseBg(), cases.getCaseStatus());
```

Edit (thanks to Mark):

If you intended to print a line separator, either use `%n` instead of `%\n`.

```
System.out.printf("%-5d%-10s%-8s%-20s%-15s%n", (count+1),per.get(count).getGender(),per.get(count).getAge()
             ,cases.getCaseBg(), cases.getCaseStatus());
```

Comment: ahhh thanks so much... this was such a roundabout question oh gosh sorry for all the extra info when it was just a typo

Comment: It is also possible the OP meant `%n` which is the format conversion for the platform specific line separator (eg `\r\n` on Windows, `\n` on Linux).

Answer (score -2):

Try to change the path to a relative path :

```java
File file = new File("../folder/file.txt");
```

".." means the precedent folder

Comment: this doesn't work either, but since all the files are located in the same place would I still need to do that?

Comment: you can, but that can be annoying